# How to return all data from Entity Framework after updating model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm Using VS2015 Community Edition MVC5 - EF6

I created a simple Model and Its CRUD Operations. Model: Person, Fields(Id, FirstName,LastName,DateofBirth...).

When I updated the model (Added two References Field with default values).

The added fields to Person Model: (Nationality_Id, City_Id), each of them are foreign keys to nationality and City tables.

When I returned to the Index Method

```
// GET: 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Person> persons = db.Persons.ToList();
    return View(persons);
}


public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public string Name4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Some Controller methods

```
    // GET: People
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Person> persons = db.Persons.ToList();
        return View(persons);
    }


    // GET: People/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Addresses = new SelectList(db.Adresses, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: People/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,DocumentCode,Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,DateOfBirth,Address")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

Here is a piece of code in create view (should be responsible on retrieving data from view)

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, ClinicDemo.App_Start.SystemTranslation.ADDRESS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownList("Address_Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Addresses, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a piece of code which should view address name depending on address_id, it still empty even in some hard coded data

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address.Name)
    </td>
```

persons object return all data without the new fields even when I set them manually from database, when I add new person all data are set correctly except those fields,

Any help?

Comment: Please show the new `Person` class and the code where yo create a new `Person`. It's hard to guess what's wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

Default values will not be populated for the old data, you will need to make those changes to the database yourself. Should be quite simple:

```
update Person set FieldName = "defaultvalue"
```

Comment: the problem also in new data. This is the error when save new record `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Address_Id', table 'aspnet-ClinicDemo-20151204092505.dbo.People'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

Comment: Please post complete code you use to add records. In the case above it looks like you are not setting AddressId field which must be not null.